# How to get specific part in MySql with group by?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a problem with SQL query, and I will try to explain what I want to do. This is my query which returns some result rows.

```
SELECT 
sck.sckid,
sck.prid,
sck.paid,
sck.sckcen,
sum(scd.scdkiek) as count_of_goods,
min(scn.scndat) as `date`
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
INNER JOIN sandeliai ON sandeliai.paid = sck.paid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 GROUP BY sckid
```

And this query returns "Table 1" of results:

Table 1:

```
sckid    |    prid    |    sckcen    |    count_of_goods    |      date     |
123      |    1376    |    10009     |          0           |   2012-12-31  |
124      |    1376    |    10007     |          15          |   2013-01-25  |
125      |    1376    |    10005     |          0           |   2013-02-13  |
126      |    1376    |    10000     |          18          |   2013-03-15  |
```

But I need just one row with all data grouped by `prid`, and I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
sck.sckid,
sck.prid,
sck.paid,
sck.sckcen,
sum(scd.scdkiek) as count_of_goods,
min(scn.scndat) as `date`
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
INNER JOIN sandeliai ON sandeliai.paid = sck.paid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 GROUP BY prid
```

Then I get one row with this data in table:

Table 2:

```
sckid    |    prid    |    sckcen    |    count_of_goods    |      date     |
123      |    1376    |    10009     |          23          |   2012-12-31  |
```

It's seems all correct, but in `date` field I need to return most earlier date from table one, which have count_of_goods > 0, so for me need this result:

Table 3:

```
sckid    |    prid    |    sckcen    |    count_of_goods    |      date     |
123      |    1376    |    10009     |          23          |   2013-01-25  |
```

So any ideas how can I get result like in Table 3?

Comment: it's data type, but for me need most earlier date from table one, which have count_of_goods > 0

Comment: Try `MAX(scn.scndat)`.

Comment: use having count_of_goods >0  order by date

Answer (score 1):

Try using `having`, something like

```
SELECT 
sck.sckid,
sck.prid,
sck.paid,
sck.sckcen,
sum(scd.scdkiek) as count_of_goods,
min(scn.scndat) as `date`
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
INNER JOIN sandeliai ON sandeliai.paid = sck.paid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 GROUP BY prid HAVING count_of_goods > 0;
```

This should work for you. This may skip some rows with count = 0 which I think should be fine (just my personal opinion).

Please take this as a starting point and not as a final solution.

**Edit:** Updated sum(...) in having with the alias

Comment: You can use count_of_goods in the `HAVING` as it uses the columns in the `GROUP`ed result set, and so the alias `count_of_goods` is valid and preferable to doing `HAVING SUM(...)`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Simonatmso.net. I have removed the statement about the having clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer I originally came back with may have been vastly overcomplex.  Assuming that scd.scdkiek is numeric and is not the id, then you may get what you want by simply changing the INNER JOIN criteria, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    sck.sckid,
    sck.prid,
    sck.paid,
    sck.sckcen,
    scn.scndat,
    SUM(scd.scdkiek) AS count_of_goods
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd 
    ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
    AND scd.scdkiek > 0
INNER JOIN sandeliai 
    ON sandeliai.paid = sck.paid
INNER JOIN scn 
    ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 
GROUP BY 
    sck.prid
```

Failing that though I would consider using a subquery.  The subquery will calculate the count_of_goods per-row.  The outer query will then use this to decide whether or not to set the date of that row to NULL.  MIN(...somedate...,NULL) will return the date.  This in turn will mean that you should get the minimum date where count_of_goods on that row is not NULL.

The subquery is grouped by date as you are looking for a date where count_of_goods is > 0.

This is just one option of course, there may be other more efficient ways, but I believe this will do as you are aiming to do

```
SELECT
    sck.sckid,
    sck.prid,
    sck.paid,
    sck.sckcen,
    SUM(d.count_of_goods) AS count_of_goods,
    MIN(IF(d.count_of_goods>0,d.scndat,NULL)) AS `date`
FROM (
    -- Get the data and group it by date
    SELECT 
        sck.sckid,
        sck.prid,
        sck.paid,
        sck.sckcen,
        scn.scndat,
        SUM(scd.scdkiek) AS count_of_goods
    FROM sck 
    INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
    INNER JOIN sandeliai ON sandeliai.paid = sck.paid
    INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
    WHERE sck.prid = 1376 
    GROUP BY 
        sck.prid, -- may not really be needed
        scn.scndat
) AS d
GROUP BY d.prid
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I my question was not very logical I try to combine both query's in my question, and then I get A good answer, this is my solution:

```
SELECT 
sck.sckid,
sck.prid,
sck.paid,
sck.sckcen,
sum(scd.scdkiek) as count_of_goods,
(SELECT 
scn.scndat
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 GROUP BY sck.sckid having sum(scd.scdkiek) > 0 ORDER BY scn.scndat LIMIT 1) as `date`
FROM sck 
INNER JOIN scd ON scd.sckid = sck.sckid
INNER JOIN scn ON scn.scnid = scd.scnid
WHERE sck.prid = 1376 GROUP BY prid;
```